# Body border with changing background-color or background-image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to build a website which has a gap / space between the browser window and the content of the website. I need this gap to stay in place even when scrolling the content.

The following image should help you understand what I mean: 
[image]

A similar effect has been explained [here](https://css-tricks.com/body-border/) and a demo can be seen [here](https://css-tricks.com/examples/BodyBorder/).

The above solutions, however, only create a border around the website that has a solid color.

The problem is that I would like to create an actual gap instead of a solid border, which is transparent so that the body of the website becomes visible through it.

I have created this fiddle trying to achieve the effect: 
https://jsfiddle.net/jascha/ozeoe2dp/57/

As you can see in the fiddle linked above, there is a gap around the content and the background of the body is visible through that gap. This gap stays in place even when scrolling the page.

I have achived that by nesting the content inside several divs. One is for the gap, the second for the scrollbar and the third div for the actual website content, like so:

```
<div class="body-border">
    <div class="scrollable-content">
        <div class="page-content">
            website content goes here
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem with my solution is that the scrollbar doesn't reach the top and bottom of the viewport because the gap is outside of the scrollbar. I can't find a way to have the gap in the inside of the scrollable div.

So my question is: How can I achive the gap to always be present around all sides of the content, even when scrolling the page, while at the same time having a normal scrollbar outside of that gap?

My guess is that jQuery is able to achive this but I really don't know how.

I hope I could explain it right, since English is not my first language. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try to make use of `border-image` instead of `background-image`...also a little bit change in html, use a separate div for border...

Also you will need to apply `pointer-events:none` to that border so that you can select the inner content

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.body-border {
  pointer-events: none;
  background-size: cover;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  border: 20px solid;
  border-image: url(https://im-01.gifer.com/ONMJ.gif) 20;
}

.scrollable-content {
  padding: 20px;
}

.page-content {
  position: relative;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="body-border"></div>
<div class="scrollable-content">
  <div class="page-content">
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, the result looks like what I want to achive but my goal is to have an actual gap, not just a border. That's because I would like to have a video or some sort of changing/moving background visible through that gap. I've updated the fiddle to make this clearer: https://jsfiddle.net/jascha/ozeoe2dp/57/

Comment: Hi, the gif is just representing a video or changes in the body background. Basically, imagine I want to have a fullscreen background video or canvas behind the page and I need that to be visible through a gap around the page content..

Answer (score 0):

**I understand now what you're wanting...try this out...**

```css
.page-content{
    margin-top: -20px;
    position: relative;
    background: white;
}

body{
    margin: 0;
    background: url(https://im-01.gifer.com/ONMJ.gif);
    background-size: cover;
    padding: 100px;
}

#left {
    left: 0;
}

#right {
    right: 0;
}
#top {
    top: 0;
}
#bottom {
    bottom: 0;
}
#left, #right {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 15px;
}

#top, #bottom {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!--<div class="body-border">
    <div class="scrollable-content">
-->        <div class="page-content">
            <p>text</p>
            <p>text</p>
            <p>text</p>
            <p>text</p>
            <p>text</p>
            <p>text</p>
            <p>text</p>
            <p>text</p>
            <p>text</p>
            <p>text</p>
            <p>text</p>
            <p>text</p>
            <p>text</p>
            <p>text</p>
            <p>text</p>
            <p>text</p>
            <p>text</p>
            <p>text</p>
            <p>text</p>
            <p>text</p>
            <p>text</p>
            <p>text</p>
            <p>text</p>
            <p>text</p>
            <p>text</p>
            <p>text</p>
            <p>text</p>
        </div>
<!--    </div>
</div>
-->

<div id="left"></div>
<div id="right"></div>
<div id="top"></div>
<div id="bottom"></div>
```

**DISREGARD**
I may be misunderstanding the question, but if you're looking for the scroll-bar to be full height of the viewport you can just move you `overflow-y: scroll;` up to the body-border div.

Comment: But the body-border div isn't scrollable since its position is fixed. You can try that in the fiddle I linked above..

Comment: Hi John, the scrollbar is in the right place but the gap doesn't stay in place when scrolling the page. The top gap isnt visible after scrolling and the bottom gap is only visible after scrolling to the end of the page.